# jQuery add space before or after value if multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

How can I add a space if an additional value for `goo` is generated before or after the original one when multiple elements are `active`?

I've tried something like `.text()+" "`

```
$('.leaflet-panel-layers-selector').click(function(){
var goo = $( ".leaflet-panel-layers-item.active" ).text();

$('#chartType').val(goo);
});
```

**UPDATE** Added Plnkr see below. When a layer is selected the name is added to the field `chartType` but when a base map is selected plus a layer I need a space between the two and no space when only one is selected.

https://embed.plnkr.co/hIBV05/

[image]

Comment: Give us your HTML as well, please.

Comment: @Phong Updated with working Plnkr

Comment: The easiest solution is to add a space after each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the click function and add this below `var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers( ... )`

```
var activeOverlayers = [];
var activeBasemap = "";
panelLayers.on('panel:selected',function(e){
    if(e.overlay){
        activeOverlayers.push(e.name);
    }else{
        activeBasemap = e.name;
    }
    generateText();
})

panelLayers.on('panel:unselected',function(e){
    if(e.overlay){
        if(activeOverlayers.indexOf(e.name) > -1){
            activeOverlayers.splice(activeOverlayers.indexOf(e.name),1);
        }
    }
    generateText();

})

function generateText(){
    var text = activeBasemap;
    if(activeOverlayers.length > 0 && activeBasemap != ""){
        text += " - " //Or repalce " - " with " "
    }
    text += activeOverlayers.join(" ");
    $('#chartType').val(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response, that works well. Just, how can I remove the `-` if only "Boston Subway" is selected? Currently it displays `- Boston Subway (T)`. I've bee testing with something like `text.replace(/^-/, '')`

Comment: This has the opposite effect where the `-` is there at the end if only a Basemap is selected but still not the desired function.

`if(activeOverlayers.length + activeBasemap.length > 1){
        text += " - "+activeOverlayers.join(" "); //Or repalce " - " with " "
       
       
    }
    
    
    
    else if(activeOverlayers.length = 1){
        text += ""+activeOverlayers.join(" "); //Or repalce " - " with " "
       
       
    }`

Comment: I updated the `generateText()` function. I hope you check my answer